# Scipy Minimize - Keep getting a singular matrix error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to optimize a 20x5 matrix to maximize a return value y. There are 1 main constraints that I need to include:

1. Total sum of all the elements must between a min and max range

However, I keep getting this singular matrix error below:

```
Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 6)
            Current function value: -3.0867160133139926
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 261
            Gradient evaluations: 1
```

I have attached the full code below. I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong?

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
import random

# Define Objective function
def obj_func(matrix):
    return np.sum(output_matrix)


# Create optimizer function
def optimizer_result(tot_min_sum, tot_max_sum, matrix_input):


    # Create constraint 1) - total matrix sum range
    constraints_list = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - tot_min_sum},
                        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -(np.sum(x) - tot_max_sum)}]


    # Create an inital matrix
    start_matrix = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(0, 20)]

    # Run optimizer
    optimizer_solution = so.minimize(cost, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0, total_matrix_max_sum)] * 260,
                                     tol=0.01,
                                     options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 100}, constraints=constraints_list,
                                     callback=callback)
    return optimizer_solution


# Initalise constraints
tot_min_sum = 0
tot_max_sum = 20000
matrix_input = np.zeros((52, 5))
matrix_input[0, 0] = 100


# Run Optimizer
y = optimizer_result(total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum, column_sum_min_lst, column_sum_max_lst, matrix_input)
print(y)
```

Comment: Using a non-deterministic initial guess `start_matrix` is a terrible idea as you'll never know whether your initial guess will be feasible. What about sing a simple initial guess that fulfills your constraints and therefore is guaranteed to be feasible?

Comment: Hi @joni,  I have made ```start_matrix = [100,200,300, 0, 0, 9900, 1800, 7700, 0, 0] + [0 for i in range(250)]```, but I'm still getting the same singular matrix issue?

Comment: Can you please post the full error message?

Comment: @Caridorc Please see below - It's attached it to the post too :)

```       Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 6)
            Current function value: -3.0867160133139926
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 261
            Gradient evaluations: 1 ```

Comment: @star_it8293 so there is not a connection to the line in your code that causes it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, unfortunately

Comment: Why do you solve this with an NLP solver? This is a linear model.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen please can you elaborate further? Apologies, I'm quite new to the field of optimization

Comment: Usually I solve linear models with linear solvers, and nonlinear models with nonlinear solvers. Like if you want to take a train it is better not to go to the airport.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Please see this post. My obj_func() is actually like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566976/modelling-5-separate-equations-into-1-equation/75569538#75569538

Is it still correct for me to use an nonlinear solver?

Comment: No, I only commented on this post. Note that your mathematical model is wrong/incomplete. There are five functions with scalar argument x, but the input is a matrix a[i,j]. So this cannot be solved as stated. It is all a big mess.

Comment: Yes, the input matrix (52x5) is of the form a[i,j]. This will then become flattened to become an array of 260 elements ```x0, x1....x259``` which will be passed into the obj_fuc(x). The solution the optimizer produces will then be re-shaped into a 52x2 matrix. Please let me know if that made sense?

Comment: There is no proper, normal mathematical model. Just some bits and pieces. Not being a mind reader, I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen please see updated post. Have added the actual ```obj_func()```

Comment: The objective seems incorrect. This will make 0 the best solution (apart from the fixed values). May you want to maximize? Again, the first thing to do is to develop a proper mathematical model, before typing in code.

Comment: Apologies have corrected it - it's meant to maximize

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a nonlinear solver for a linear problem. With an objective being the sum of the matrix, and your stated bounds, the problem is trivial: set the fixed elements of 100, 200, 300, and leave the rest 0. `milp` will tell you as much:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

I = 52
J = 5

matrix_input = np.zeros((I, J))
matrix_input[0, 0] = 100
matrix_input[0, 1] = 200
matrix_input[0, 2] = 300

total_matrix_min_sum = 0
total_matrix_max_sum = 20000
column_sum_min_lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
column_sum_max_lst = [10000, 2000, 8000, 0, 0]

# minimize sum of entire matrix
c = np.ones(I*J)

n_fixed = np.count_nonzero(matrix_input)
n_constraint = J + n_fixed + 1
A = np.empty((n_constraint, I*J))
lb = np.empty(n_constraint)
ub = np.empty(n_constraint)

# column bounds
A[:J, :] = np.tile(np.eye(J), (1, I))
lb[:J] = column_sum_min_lst
ub[:J] = column_sum_max_lst

# fixed elements
fixed_flat = matrix_input.ravel()
fixed_idx = fixed_flat.nonzero()
fixed_vals = fixed_flat[fixed_idx]
fixed = np.zeros((n_fixed, I*J))
fixed[np.arange(n_fixed), fixed_idx] = 1
A[J:-1, :] = fixed
lb[J:-1] = fixed_vals
ub[J:-1] = fixed_vals

# total matrix sum bounds
A[-1, :] = 1
lb[-1] = total_matrix_min_sum
ub[-1] = total_matrix_max_sum

result = milp(
    c=c,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),  # the only simple constraint is the overall lower bound of 0
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=A, lb=lb, ub=ub),
)
print(result.message)
x = result.x.reshape((I, J))
```

Comment: Hi @Reinderien, my obj_func() is actually like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566976/modelling-5-separate-equations-into-1-equation. The input is a 52x5 matrix, the output is single number which I'm trying to maximise. Would I still be using ```milp``` for this case?

Comment: No, but that isn't what your question says

Comment: have added the actual ```obj_func``` now

Comment: not sure where I can pass my ```obj_func``` in your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I reversed engineered a mathematical model.

[image]

Minimization pushed all variables toward zero, so I switched the objective to maximization. I also assumed the variables are non-negative.

This is a non-convex model, so you need a global solver to make sure you don't end up in a local minimum. I gave the solver Baron 10 minutes, and it came up with:

```
----     75 VARIABLE x.L  cell values

             col1        col2        col3

row1      100.000     200.000     300.000
row9                             7700.000
row13                1800.000
row43    9900.000
```

This is not yet proven globally optimal: the reported gap is 4%. Could not find any better solutions than this. Of course, there may be things I have incorrectly interpreted or even implemented (first runs should be taken with a grain of salt).

Comment: I'd to like to also mention, the aim for this project is to do black box optimization (BBO) - thus I can't make any prior assumptions about the objective function. I have few questions. 1) For BBO we don't know if the model is convex or not hence thus would you solve then? 2) Which is best optimization algorithm for this problem? I used SLSQP before.

Comment: Come on. Everytime we hear: but the real problem is different. This is no way to ask for help.

Comment: Also will look in Baron :). Which is the best open-source tool you'd recommend for this problem? (that can scale well for production)

Comment: Sincere apologies, completely forgot to mention the BBO part. I think I've mentioned everything now. Please let me know if there's anything else missing.

Comment: Also regarding the model just created, please can this done for maximization (not minimization)

Comment: Black-box optimization (or DFO) + finding global solutions + scaling up is not a feasible combination.