# Modelling 6 separate equations into 1 equation

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-modeling

I have 6 functions of the form `y = beta*(exp(alpha*x/n))`. Each `func` has specific parameters as displayed in the table below.

The input is a 10x6 matrix and the output is a single value. The aim is to optimize the 10x6 matrix to produce the largest y value. Each column of the matrix has it's own function (i.e func1 for column1 etc).

Is there a way I could model all 6 functions as 1 equation?

```
y = beta*(exp(alpha*x/n))

        n    alpha  beta
func1   1.3   434   415
func2   1.4   333   102
func3   1.1   344   512
func4   1.1   434   262
func5   1.9   243   431
func6   3.9   213   421
```

I'm thinking if a model like a linear regessor should be used in this case?

Comment: What do you image the inputs and outputs of the resulting equation to be? You have 5 single variable functions. Will the result also be single variable? And for what purpose would it be used? I am having trouble understanding the questoin.

Comment: @CognizantApe Please see added details

Answer (score 1):

You could compute a new function that is just a max of those functions. That wouldn't save you anything computationally but at least you would conceptually just have one function. Since all of your functions are monotonic you could make that more efficient by determining which function is the max for at most 5 intervals. But it ends up being only 3 intervals when I plotted it:

[image: Note That only 3 functions are relevant]

You can get the precise algebraic points by solving for `x` in your above equations. But I will be honest, I don't understand why one would do that optimization work with only 50 samples and 5 functions instead of just taking the `max`.