# Scipy Optimize - Singular Matrix issue when creating constraints in a loop

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to optimize a 20x5 matrix to maximize a return value y. There are main type of constraints that I need to include:

Total sum of all the elements must between a min and max range

However, I keep getting this singular matrix error as below when I try to create the constraints in a loop.

```
Singular matrix C in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 6)
            Current function value: -3.0867160133139926
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 261
            Gradient evaluations: 1
```

**1) Creating constraints in a loop version**

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
import random

# Define Objective function
def obj_func(matrix):
    # Define the functions for each column
    return np.sum(output_matrix)


# Create optimizer function
def optimizer_result(tot_sum_max, tot_sum_min, col_min, col_max, matrix_input):

    constraints_list = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - tot_sum_max},
                        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -(np.sum(x) - tot_sum_min)}]

    # Create an inital matrix
    start_matrix = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(0, 260)]

    # Run optimizer
    optimizer_solution = so.minimize(obj_func, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0, tot_sum_max)] * 20,
                                     tol=0.01,
                                     options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 100}, constraints=constraints_list,
                                     callback=callback)
```

However, the optimizer works fine when I manually type in the constraints, as displayed below. (Note: did not include all 260 element constraints for simplicity). Unsure why this is the case?

**2) Manually creating constraints version**

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
import random

# Define Objective function
def obj_func(matrix):
    return np.sum(output_matrix)


# Create optimizer function
def optimizer_result(tot_sum_max, tot_sum_min, col_min, col_max, matrix_input):

total_and_col_cons =[{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - tot_sum_min},
                       {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -(np.sum(x) - tot_sum_max)}]

    # Create an inital matrix
    start_matrix = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(0, 260)]

    # Run optimizer
    optimizer_solution = so.minimize(obj_func, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0, tot_sum_max)] * 20,
                                     tol=0.01,
                                     options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 100}, constraints=constraints_list,
                                     callback=callback)
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that that's your objective function? Because I'm pretty sure it isn't

Comment: This is a non-representative example, or alternatively, it's representative and your implementation is overkill. For instance, you only have three fixed matrix elements, and none of them share a column.

Comment: Are you tied to scipy for some reason or are you open to alternate framework?  And are you going to substitute in some non-linear objective function later (big change)?  A couple-line LP can "minimize" this matrix easily.

Comment: Using more advanced NLP solvers, this really is an extremely small and easy problem. Of course, we don't know what the real objective looks like.

Comment: @Reinderien have added the actual objective function. Please see updates :)

Comment: @AirSquid nope, not tied to Scipy. Please can you suggest how I can implement with other frameworks?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, Please see the updated post. Have added the actual objective function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scipy Minimize - Keep getting a singular matrix error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566743/scipy-minimize-keep-getting-a-singular-matrix-error)

Comment: @star_it8293 @Reinderien already gave you an answer to your other (duplicate) initial question. You only need to use `minimize` instead of `milp` and pass your objective. You can use all of his defined bounds and constraints.

Comment: @joni not sure I understand what you mean? I'm already using ```minimize``` in my original script?

Comment: I was trying to say that you only need to use Reinderien's code in the other question and use minimize instead of milp by passing your nonlinear objective function. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Various failures to vectorise. There should only be five dictionary constraints, and not a single loop.

More broadly, your examples remain trivial and unhelpful. The sum minima do not produce any interesting results until they are changed from 0. Or if they're 0 in real life, then your approach needs extreme simplification.

```py
from typing import Sequence, Callable, Literal

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, OptimizeResult


def maximize(
    objective: Callable[[np.ndarray], float],
    column_min_sums: Sequence[float], total_matrix_min_sum: float,
    column_max_sums: Sequence[float], total_matrix_max_sum: float,
    fixed_elements: np.ndarray, **kwargs,
) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # optimised matrix
    OptimizeResult,
]:
    height, num_channels = fixed_elements.shape

    def get_x(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return matrix.reshape(fixed_elements.shape)

    def cost(matrix: np.ndarray) -> float:
        return -objective(get_x(matrix))

    def make_fixed() -> dict:
        flat = fixed_elements.ravel()
        idx = flat.nonzero()
        values = flat[idx]
        def constraint(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
            return matrix.ravel()[idx] - values
        return {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint}

    def make_col(sign: Literal[1, -1], bound: np.ndarray) -> dict:
        def constraint(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
            slack = get_x(matrix).sum(axis=0) - bound
            return sign*slack.ravel()
        return {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint}

    def make_total(sign: Literal[1, -1], bound: float) -> dict:
        def constraint(matrix: np.ndarray) -> float:
            return sign*(matrix.sum() - bound)
        return {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint}

    # These constraints are not strictly necessary, but a
    # better-constrained problem is one that converges faster
    lb = fixed_elements.ravel()
    epsilon = 1e-6  # needed or else LSTSQ gets a singular matrix
    ub = np.tile(-fixed_elements.sum(axis=0) + column_max_sums, (height, 1)) + epsilon
    ub[fixed_elements != 0] = fixed_elements[fixed_elements != 0] + epsilon
    ub = ub.ravel()

    result = minimize(
        fun=cost,
        x0=fixed_elements.ravel(),
        method='SLSQP',
        bounds=Bounds(lb=lb, ub=ub),
        constraints=(
            make_fixed(),
            make_col(+1, column_min_sums),
            make_col(-1, column_max_sums),
            make_total(+1, total_matrix_min_sum),
            make_total(-1, total_matrix_max_sum),
        ),
        **kwargs,
    )
    x = get_x(result.x)
    return x, result


def test() -> None:
    fixed_elements = np.zeros((52, 5))
    fixed_elements[0, :3] = 100, 200, 300

    beta, alpha, n = np.array((
        (215882.325432, 8.753072e-9, 1.748360),
        ( 82822.551415, 1.755287e-7, 1.592804),
        ( 43052.061514, 3.319054e-8, 1.778913),
        (307295.664100, 7.896846e-9, 1.508320),
        (215882.325432, 8.753072e-9, 1.748360),
    )).T

    def objective(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
        y = beta * (1 - np.exp(-alpha * x**n))
        return y.sum()

    x, result = maximize(
        objective=objective,
        fixed_elements=fixed_elements,
        total_matrix_min_sum=650,
        total_matrix_max_sum=20_000,
        column_min_sums=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        column_max_sums=(10_000, 2_000, 8_000, 10, 10),
    )

    np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000)
    print(result.message)
    print('Sum:', x.sum())
    print('Column sums:', x.sum(axis=0))
    print('Matrix:')
    print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

```
Iteration limit reached
Sum: 19999.99999274707
Column sums: [1.00000000e+04 1.99999999e+03 7.99800000e+03 1.00000116e+00 1.00000000e+00]
Matrix:
[[1.00000000e+02 2.00000000e+02 3.00000000e+02 8.24482343e-07 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 4.61812983e-13 1.00718942e-06 1.36608889e-07 9.69551938e-14]
 [0.00000000e+00 3.57445830e+02 1.67830277e-06 4.73313295e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 3.76965344e-04 2.43650600e+02 4.73325851e-08 1.55587265e-01]
 [8.94890545e-07 1.58105749e-12 1.09317345e-06 5.14911909e-07 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.90798932e-05 3.59217683e+02 5.26518769e-07 4.73319857e-08 1.84615974e-13]
 [4.88262209e-14 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 4.73330657e-08 3.14701650e-13]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.60513126e-06 5.14910250e-07 1.11780551e-12]
 [0.00000000e+00 2.65772424e-14 0.00000000e+00 4.73326259e-08 2.02992906e-13]
 [0.00000000e+00 3.17354894e-13 1.00719222e-06 1.05943237e-07 0.00000000e+00]
 [1.25896319e-15 3.60967799e+02 1.91702506e-06 4.73314960e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [6.36097311e-16 2.31025953e-03 2.43650600e+02 4.73302362e-08 7.71382083e-01]
 [8.94893759e-07 0.00000000e+00 1.11094166e-06 4.73322415e-08 1.99719420e-13]
 [4.90799204e-05 3.50300705e+02 1.55347250e-07 4.73321550e-08 2.45594390e-13]
 [1.10726081e-14 3.52725455e-14 1.78883854e-13 7.59945342e-06 1.94483354e-13]
 [4.22121704e-15 0.00000000e+00 1.15840614e-06 4.73326193e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [1.45666586e-14 3.14094465e-14 0.00000000e+00 4.73323245e-08 2.08610450e-13]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.16068443e-14 1.14385569e-06 4.73321702e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.48737158e+01 1.15743594e-06 4.73306963e-08 2.04034868e-13]
 [1.79011766e-14 1.68211390e-03 2.45534293e+02 4.73332418e-08 7.30306482e-02]
 [8.94909115e-07 2.02105109e-13 1.24629063e-06 4.73320996e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.90993525e-05 3.57189890e+02 1.13479740e-06 4.73317314e-08 2.78310832e-14]
 [0.00000000e+00 8.90011998e-14 1.79228376e-13 1.36608075e-07 1.67812611e-13]
 [2.80955208e-14 1.31493103e-13 1.67830305e-06 4.73323279e-08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.40680045e-13 0.00000000e+00 4.73321795e-08 1.96762239e-13]
 [1.63649184e-08 0.00000000e+00 1.37088197e-06 3.84611702e-02 7.29256617e-11]
 [4.82548953e+02 2.18038969e-13 2.92419689e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13617368e-10]
 [4.72913421e+02 1.96257525e-13 2.47586706e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.28822660e-11]
 [4.81932194e+02 2.05133211e-13 2.46561929e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.28935069e-11]
 [4.82434957e+02 2.38452781e-13 3.25175823e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13677961e-10]
 [4.74346992e+02 1.39464284e-13 2.47895011e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.29088785e-11]
 [4.83025385e+02 9.09411430e-14 2.45288593e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13767175e-10]
 [4.72411601e+02 1.62685842e-13 2.73634670e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13793111e-10]
 [4.81885574e+02 1.22040808e-13 2.44964384e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.29378171e-11]
 [4.83204693e+02 0.00000000e+00 2.93617855e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13696255e-10]
 [4.74986002e+02 1.59931146e-13 2.54974228e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.28950527e-11]
 [4.81597638e+02 2.82448620e-14 2.46255974e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.29157449e-11]
 [5.20870573e+02 4.59558644e-13 3.24689479e+02 3.84611702e-02 4.13751014e-10]
 [4.77516633e+02 0.00000000e+00 2.45387613e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.80412934e+02 4.96323867e-13 2.45653839e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.69377153e-11]
 [1.00661261e+02 1.14770387e-13 3.23599491e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.68602200e-11]
 [6.52684112e+01 2.99456116e-13 2.45362582e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.72826034e+02 1.68633129e-13 2.48808450e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.65157181e-11]
 [1.64507420e+02 4.96874547e-14 2.45763981e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [1.03716145e+02 5.02970556e-13 2.45567316e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.81267154e+02 1.92728307e-13 2.75764476e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.67999527e-11]
 [1.46552745e+02 9.77607407e-14 2.45609216e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.64366025e+02 1.37565482e-13 2.53933121e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.68155200e-11]
 [4.73566329e+02 6.20944884e-14 3.15116448e+02 3.84611702e-02 7.68952495e-11]
 [1.04739598e+02 2.03781836e-13 2.44066599e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.67403119e+02 0.00000000e+00 3.24166755e+02 4.73326510e-08 7.69553454e-11]
 [1.05038061e+02 4.83901038e-13 2.63300258e+02 3.84611702e-02 0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Apologies, have added a cost function now. Forgot to add negative (as this a maximization problem)

Comment: I'd to like to also mention, the aim for this project is to be do black box optimization - thus I can't make any prior assumptions about the objective function.

Comment: @star_it8293 that's an incoherent goal and somewhat of a lie. You do need to make assumptions about the objective function: that it operates on a matrix of known size full of continuous, positive variables, etc. This guessing game could go on forever. You need to spell out _exactly_ what you do and don't assume about the input to your API.

Comment: @star_it8293 What is the purpose of "masking the objective parameters"?

Comment: those are actual values used in the model - thus will need to mask to maintain anonymity